# How is failover handled in Reverse Proxies like Nginx/HAProxy

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, failover

I am trying to understand how Reverse Proxies like Nginx/HAProxy handle fault-tolerance and reliability when there are Keep-Alive connections.

Imagine a scenario, where millions (or a few hundred thousands) of end users have keep-alive connections with Nginx cluster of servers to keep receiving updates frequently about some kind of data. Is this possible with Nginx? How are fault-tolerance and resiliency handled in such scenarios?